# Format r output in knitr

Tags: html, r, knitr

I'm trying to build an html page showing some output (max values, time recorded,...) inside a table. I'm using knitr for the first time in this type of reports

I have tried this code

````
<table>
<td class="celda1">
```{r results='asis', echo=FALSE}
print(output$Temperatura)
```
</td><td class="celda2">
```{r results='asis', echo=FALSE}
output$Hora1
```
</td>
</table>
````

with these results

[image]

Now I would like to remove the prefix number `[1]` just before the value. I am not familiar with knitr but have read some options for code chunks to remove warnings or ## comments but can't find how to remove the prefix.

Thanks in advance for your help

**SOLUTION**

Finally the solution came from the combination of `cat` and `paste` commands, following suggestion from @drmariod. Just `cat` for numeric values and `cat-paste` to preserve date format.

````
<table>
<td class="celda1">
```{r results='asis', echo=FALSE}
cat(output$Temperatura)
```
</td><td class="celda2">
```{r results='asis', echo=FALSE}
cat(paste(output$Hora1))
```
</td>
</table>
````

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if you're trying to embed R code into an existing html page, but if you're just using R by itself, you don't the <table> tags. Instead, you can use the `kable` function to create formatted HTML tables with `knitr`. Then the indices/prefix numbers won't appear. See the section on tables in `knit` for example here: https://sachsmc.github.io/knit-git-markr-guide/knitr/knit.html

Comment: Hi @meenaparam I have also tried `kable` and in makes nice tables if you want to plot the complete data frame as a table. But I just want to extract some values and put into a previous html table with its own html design. `kable` still remains as an alternative if I can build a whole new table with just the output I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `cat` instead! like `cat(output$Hora1)`

Comment: Hi @drmariod It works perfect for the numeric var but it changes the datetime format to `1502892000`. Gonna search for controlling `cat` output

Comment: I just wanted to asked what is the type of `output$Hora1` and maybe `as.character` might help :-)